# Profile image in my site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, my-site

I have changed the profile image for My site in a SharePoint 2013 environment. I want to add a question that. Is the profile image in synchronization with the Active Directory. ?

I do not have a picture attached in the active directory but the my site is showing the image I uploaded. I have been working for to sync the image with Active Directory but not able to do so.

Kindly let me know if we can have a synchronization between Active directory and My site profile image.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, you can have the image imported from your AD but it requires you to use User Profile Synchronization, as it won't work with AD-import. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx

Comment: I have user profile synchronization service running in my environment. but still the picture remains same as that i have uploaded in My Site.

Comment: There's some more configuration to do.
http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2013/05/13/adding-pictures-to-active-directory-and-show-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: have followed the steps but still it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Add the steps/what you have tried. Will be easier to find what's not working

Comment: 1. Created a user profile synchronization service and attached it with the web application.
2. Sync settings kept as - Use SharePoint Active Directory Import.
3. Started a full sync.
4. Updated as per the steps given in http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2013/05/13/adding-pictures-to-active-directory-and-show-in-sharepoint-2013/
5. Started a full Sync again.